# Объясните простым языком и подробно, что происходит

Tags: java, массивы

Сам код:

```
class Gauss {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] ia = new int[101];
    for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++) ia[i] = i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int e : ia) sum += e;
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

Объясните пожалуйста подробно, что происходит в этих действиях:

```
ia[i] = i;
```

и

```
for (int e : ia)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `ia[i] = i;` Массиву с индексом i присваивается значение i
2. `for (int e : ia)`. Если не ошибаюсь, то это просто сокращение подобной записи:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++){
           sum += ia[i];
   }
   ```

Общий смысл кода: сумма чисел с 0 до 100

Comment: Спасибо! Вот чес слово, не догадался бы что скрывается за этим выражением: for (int e : ia)

Comment: @danilshik, от 0 до 101

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Уверены? добавьте строчку System.out.println(i);} в 1 цикл

Comment: @danilshik Да, вы правы! -100500 мне в карму!

Answer (score 3):

В первой строке вы просто присваиваите индексу `i` массива `ia` значение `i`. Получается если `i` равно 7, тогда 7-ой индекс *ia* будет равен 7.

Далее вы используете цикл перебора - [foreach](/questions/tagged/foreach), который просто перебирает массив. [Документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, ознакомлюсь.